# At Shacharit at exactly which point does one have to put Teffilin on and off?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tefilin

If someone cannot put on Teffilin at home prior going to Synagogue and wants to put them on when inside the Synagogue, when is the **exact** moment of putting them on?

Right at the Start of Shacharit? Or may be a little later if the minyan has started already?

And when exactly may one remove them? At the very end or a bit earlier if rushing to the office?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yochanan and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Every single moment is a Mitzva, so probably as soon as reasonably feasible and as late as reasonably feasible respectively (absent any arbitrary local customs that is)

Answer (score 8):

See https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Putting_On_and_Removing_Tefillin

The minhag is to put on Tefillin in the Synagogue after having said Birchot HaShachar and Birchot HaTorah but preferably before the Shema in Korbanot and at least before Parshat HaTamid. Kaf Hachaim 25,3-4

The minimum requirement is to have Tefillin on during Kriyat Shema and Shmoneh Esrei. Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 25,4

One should wait until at least the kedusha of uva litzion before removing one's Tefillin.Shulchan aruch Orach Chaim 25,13
But ideally wait till the mourner's kaddish that takes place after alenu leshabeach and Al ken to take off one's Tefillin when finished the Prayers (mishna Brura Orach Chaim 25,13 55 quoting Arizal).

Comment: Most Western Ashkenazi Jews put it on right before _Baruch Sheamar_

Comment: @Kazibácsi while that may be what you see, remember saying the Shema without Tefilin is like Being Meid Eidus Sheker al atzmo i think thats why the Kaf Hachaim was Makpid on putting on Tefilin before Shema in Korbonos

Comment: I would rephrase it like "the minhag of Kaf haChaim was etc." while others put it on later. We only say the first verse, which may be the reason for the different tradition.

Comment: @kazibacsi it seems that your tradition of putting tefillin after Shema in korbonos might be a _minhag betaus_ so I suggest you speak to your posek and he'll probably tell you to do like the KafHachaim said to put you're tefillin on before Kerias Shema in Korbonos. Rabbi Willig on halachapedia knows exactly what he is talking about

Comment: @yosefkorn Before making such unfounded claims, check a few works (R' Heidenheim, [Sefas Yisroel p. 20](https://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Tefiloh-Sefas-Yisroel-1-Shacharit.pdf). Obviously the Kaf haChaim is a very strong authority, but his rulings are not obligatory for all. (BTW with that _minhag_ you might risk in winter putting _talit_ and _tefilin_ too early.)

Comment: @kazibacsi this post is not talking about minyanim that start before misheyakir, most synagogues have Rabbis to tell their congregants what to do in such situations. If you want to ask a separate question of what is best to do when davening before misheyakir, you can bring your source and give your answer that's what the sight is here for.

Comment: @yosefkorn You are not answering to the relevant part. If there is someone, who is _machmir_ for a certain reason, and has a different _minhag,_ it doesn't mean that the others are fools. Both R' Ulla and R' Chiya bar Abba lived before the [Persian opression](https://www.beureihatefila.com/files/L_Olam_Yihei_Odom_Yirei_Shamayim.pdf), so they are talking about the "normal Shema." Again, if the Kaf haChaim is _machmir_ on this, great, but it doesn't change the _halakhah_ cited in the answer.